# What is Process CreateTime in the xml procmon saved?

Tags: windows, process, procmon, process-monitor

Process data in the xml file Procmon saved has "CreateTime". For a process starting from 2023/4/17 14:36:01, its CreateTime in the xml file is 133261869619355124. Regardless of whether this CreateTime is regarded as a nanosecond, millisecond or microsecond timestamp, it cannot correspond to its actual creation time.What is CreateTime？

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeBEc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3EHN.png)

Comment: If you spend any time working with windows times, you'll come to learn about ticks - the number of 100ns intervals since 01/01/0001. This looks like that.

Comment: It's a [`FILETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) value - the number or 100ns ticks since Jan 1st 1601.